# How to disable installing from unknown sources?

Tags: settings, unknown-sources

Is there a way to disable the phone from installing apps from unknown sources?
I know that it is possible by just going to.

`settings->security->unchceck "unknown resources"`

[image: Unknown Sources]

**But when kids install apps, a dialog appears:**

[image: Blocked]

By just tapping on settings, they can **Enable** it again and install the application.

is there a way to disable it and the dialog won't come out or make it grey so it won't be clicked/tap it again? Without putting password on my `Settings`.

Comment: Speaking of "Kids" the first things coming to mind are: 1) using a restricted profile for them, 2) using a specific "kid protection" app. For the latter be welcome to take a look at my corresponding app listings: [Child protection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/childprotect) and [App Locker: Child protection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker#group_451).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android OS Lollipop and above, you should create a guest mode for anyone you wish to hand over your cell phone, you can define the rights in the guest mode.

Comment: How to create a guest mode? any tutorial site please?

Comment: @kiLLua some phones don't have guest mode option but if yours does, check the link to see how to access it https://www.greenbot.com/article/3056569/android/how-to-switch-to-guest-mode-when-you-let-someone-borrow-your-phone.html

Comment: My phone's OS is Nougat

Comment: Drag down the notification to the full then you will see a profile icon and besides that an edit icon (Pencil Icon), click that and you will be guided accordingly.